# Show that Pn is an (n+1)-dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Show that $P_n = \{$Polynomials with real coefficients of degree $≤ n\}$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of the infinite-dimensional vector space of all real polynomials.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you know what the definition of a subspace is?  Do you know what the dimension of a vector space is?  Do you know how to prove that $P_n$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, I know what a subspace and a dimension of a vector space are.  I'm just relatively new to proofs so I always feel lost when I'm trying to prove something

Comment: In the future, keep in mind that you'll get much better feedback if you include some thoughts/work of your own in the question. For example, you might say something like "I'm having trouble coming up with a basis of $n+1$ vectors" or "I think these functions work, but how do I prove that they're linearly independent?".

Comment: alright thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of algebra to show that the set $\{1,x,x^2, \dotsc, x^n\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors. They will therefore span a vector space of dimension $n+1$.

Comment: "*Use the fundamental theorem of algebra to show that the set $\{1,x,x^2, \dotsc, x^n\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors.*"??? Have you missed the construction of polynomial rings, and confuse a polynomial with its associated polynomial function? (Not that this won't be a frequent mistake.)

Comment: The OP is at the begining of his career and is learning how to apply the definition of a vector space and linear independence. I believe that one should pick answers which corresponds to the student's current level. Learning is an iterative process.

Comment: Let's suppose that I agree with you (although I don't). Where is then the  fundamental theorem of algebra involved in your proof?

Comment: Suppose $r_j \in \mathbb{R}$ have been found such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : \sum_{j=1}^n r_j x^j = 0$, then $p(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n r_j x^j$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ which has infinitely many roots. The fundamental theorem of algebra implies that $p$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: The result you invoke is not [the fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). It's an immediate consequence of the [little Bézout theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Comment: The OP had not presented his thoughts, but appeared stuck at the begining. In such situations I prefer to give him a nugde in the right direction, rather than supply him with a text book answer. I have not seen an introdutionary level text book which does not state the required result as the first result after the fundamental theorem of algebra. My goal is to facilitate student learning. This is an iterative process and the OP can return to the question when he has complete additional classes.