# Show that $P_n$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of the vector space of all real polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that $P_n$ = {polynomials with real coefficients of degree $\leq$ n} is an ($n+1$)-dimensional subspace of the infinite-dimensional vector space of all real polynomials

I know that $P_n$ is referring to $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$

Also, I understand why the vector space of all real polynomials is infinite-dimensional (I have proved this by contradiction)

But I need help understanding why $P_n$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of it

I realize this question has already been asked here [Show that Pn is an (n+1)-dimensional subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645297/show-that-pn-is-an-n1-dimensional-subspace), but that question was marked off topic and most of the answers are giving the asker advice on how to better ask his question and thus I am asking again.

Comment: So you have written the elements in a certain form. Does that perhaps let you guess a basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that $\{1,x,\dots , x^n\}$ is a basis of $P_n$.

Comment: I found that but how do I relate that to the answer

Comment: If a vector space has a basis of $n+1$ elements then its dimension is $n+1.$